# views from another app doesnt work in django?

Tags: python, django

I have two apps 
1. posts
2. boards.
I need to create url link in boards template to view from posts app.

my root urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^', include('boards.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('posts.urls',  namespace="posts")),

]
```

posts.urls:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from views import (
    listofposts,
    create_post,
    detail,
    update_post,
    category,
    )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/', 
        create_post ,
        name='create_post'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        category,
        name='category'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$',
        update_post,
        name = 'update_post'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        detail,
        name = 'detail'),
    url(r'^$',
        listofposts ,
        name='listofpost'),
]
```

Boards template link

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'posts:listofposts' %}">Home</a>
```

I got the mistake :

Exception Value:

```
Reverse for 'listofposts' not found. 'listofposts' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: I think you have a typo here url(r'^$', listofposts , name='listofpost'). It's name should be 'listofposts'

Comment: I renamed it and got Exception Value:  

u'posts' is not a registered namespace Error during template rendering

In template /var/www/MyBlog/blog/templates/base_boards.html, error at line 15

Comment: @question1 are you sure that posts are added into setting apps?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
    'posts',
    'accounts', 
    'boards', 
]def listofposts(request, category_slug = None):
 html = 'base.html'
 query_set_list = Post.objects.all()
 query = request.GET.get("q")
 if query:
  query_set_list = query_set_list.filter(title__icontains=query)
 if category_slug:
  category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
  products = Post.filter(category=category)
 context = {
  "title" : 'Записки',
  "list" : query_set_list,
 }
 return render(request, html, context)